# How to pass ArrayList<ArrayList<customtype>> between activities

Tags: android, arraylist

How to pass `ArrayList` of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<CustomObject>>` between `activites`? I have already implemented `Parcelable` with `customObject` model class.  When I pass like `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("catVideoList", categoriesVideoList)` its gives error. I know how to pass `ArrayList` like `ArrayList<CustomObject>`.

**Below is my model class:**

```
public class VideoContentModel implements Parcelable {
    String videoId;
    String videoUrl;
    String videoTitle;
    String videoDescription;
    String videoThumbnailUrl;
    String videoDuration;
    String videoBitrate;
    String videoPublishDate;
    String videoCreateDate;
    String videoUpdateDate;
    String videoChannelId;
    String videoChannelName;
    String videoFeedType;

    public VideoContentModel(String videoId, String videoUrl, String videoTitle,
                             String videoThumbnailUrl, String videoDuration,
                             String videoBitrate, String videoPublishDate, String videoCreateDate,
                             String videoUpdateDate, String videoChannelId, String videoChannelName,
                             String videoFeedType, String videoDescription) 
    {
        this.videoId = videoId;
        this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
        this.videoTitle = videoTitle;
        this.videoThumbnailUrl = videoThumbnailUrl;
        this.videoDuration = videoDuration;
        this.videoBitrate = videoBitrate;
        this.videoPublishDate = videoPublishDate;
        this.videoCreateDate = videoCreateDate;
        this.videoUpdateDate = videoUpdateDate;
        this.videoChannelId = videoChannelId;
        this.videoChannelName = videoChannelName;
        this.videoFeedType = videoFeedType;
        this.videoDescription = videoDescription;
    }

    public String getVideoId() {
        return videoId;
    }

    public String getVideoUrl() {
        return videoUrl;
    }

    public String getVideoTitle() {
        return videoTitle;
    }

    public String getVideoDescription() {
        return videoDescription;
    }

    public String getVideoThumbnailUrl() {
        return videoThumbnailUrl;
    }

    public String getVideoDuration() {
        return videoDuration;
    }

    public String getVideoBitrate() {
        return videoBitrate;
    }

    public String getVideoPublishDate() {
        return videoPublishDate;
    }

    public String getVideoCreateDate() {
        return videoCreateDate;
    }

    public String getVideoUpdateDate() {
        return videoUpdateDate;
    }

    public String getVideoChannelId() {
        return videoChannelId;
    }

    public String getVideoChannelName() {
        return videoChannelName;
    }

    public String getVideoFeedType() {
        return videoFeedType;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.videoId);
        dest.writeString(this.videoUrl);
        dest.writeString(this.videoTitle);
        dest.writeString(this.videoDescription);
        dest.writeString(this.videoThumbnailUrl);
        dest.writeString(this.videoDuration);
        dest.writeString(this.videoBitrate);
        dest.writeString(this.videoPublishDate);
        dest.writeString(this.videoCreateDate);
        dest.writeString(this.videoUpdateDate);
        dest.writeString(this.videoChannelId);
        dest.writeString(this.videoChannelName);
        dest.writeString(this.videoFeedType);
    }

    protected VideoContentModel(Parcel in) {
        this.videoId = in.readString();
        this.videoUrl = in.readString();
        this.videoTitle = in.readString();
        this.videoDescription = in.readString();
        this.videoThumbnailUrl = in.readString();
        this.videoDuration = in.readString();
        this.videoBitrate = in.readString();
        this.videoPublishDate = in.readString();
        this.videoCreateDate = in.readString();
        this.videoUpdateDate = in.readString();
        this.videoChannelId = in.readString();
        this.videoChannelName = in.readString();
        this.videoFeedType = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<VideoContentModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<VideoContentModel>() {
        @Override
        public VideoContentModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new VideoContentModel(source);
        }

        @Override
        public VideoContentModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new VideoContentModel[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: add error......

Comment: Use `putExtra` and `getParcelable` for to pass the object between activities.

Comment: @Pravin following error display  'The method putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<ArrayList<VideoContentModel>>)'

Answer (score 1):

Parcelable is unnecessary here, as you are using simple objects (String). 
ArrayList implements Serializable and so should your CustomObject.
Once you change it, you can use

```
intent.putExtra("name", yourArrayList);
```

or

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("name", yourArrayList);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, yourActivity.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

And retrieve it in your second activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gson library for this, no need to implement parcelable.

Suppose your arraylist is :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<CustomObject>> outer = new ArrayList<>();
```

After populating it, you can add it to the intent as below :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("randomdata", new Gson().toJson(outer));
```

You can later retrieve this in Activity2 as below :

```
String extra = getIntent().getStringExtra("randomdata");
ArrayList<ArrayList<CustomObject>> list = new Gson().fromJson(extra, new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<CustomObject>>>(){}.getType());
```

Hope it helps.